# My simple python game wont work please identify my mistakes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, python-requests

```
from random import randint
import sys
l2= ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = l2[randint(0,2)]
wins = 0
losses = 0

player = False

while player == False:
    player = input("Rock," "Paper," "Scissors")
    if player == computer:
        print("Tie")    
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win Congrats")
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win Congrats")    
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Try again")
        else:
            print("You won")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You won")
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You won")
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You won")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid play Game Over for you")
    player = False
    computer = l2[randint(0,2)]
```

My code won't run for some reason and it only shows on the terminal the else statement. I dunno what I did wrong. Please help me, beginner here learning python and making some simple projects to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should't add python 2.x and python 3.x tags on the same question. For simplicity I tried your code on 3.x and it partially works.
Second, describe your problem. Don't just write "wont run for some reason".
Third, describe what you want to achieve. I will do this for you as an example.

Your game works like this:

1. Determine what computer does (works)
2. Ask what the player does (works partially)
3. Compare player and computer action and print result (doesn't work)
4. Start over at 1 (doesn't work)

Your first problem is your while loop, you should do something like this:

```
while True:
```

Why? You want a never ending loop only if the player enters a wrong action, then you want to force the loop to end, you do this with an "break" statement.

Your second problem is, you use too many if-else constructs, you don't need that many to handle all cases. Here is my working Python 3 code:

```
from random import randint
import sys

l2 = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = None
player = None
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

def win():
    global wins
    wins += 1 
    print("You win")

def loss():
    global losses
    losses += 1
    print("You lose")

def tie():
    global ties
    ties += 1
    print("Game ended with a tie")

while True:
    # determine computer action
    computer = l2[randint(0,2)]
    player = input("Choose your action. Possible values are Rock, Paper or Scissors.\n")
    if player not in l2:
        print("Invalid choice, game will end now.")
        print("You won {0} games and lost {1} games, {2} game(s) ended with a tie.".format(wins, losses, ties))
        # ending the loop
        break
    if player == computer:
        tie()
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            win()
        else:
            loss()
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            loss()
        else:
            win()   
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            loss()
        else:
            win()
```

If you have any questions, ask.

Edit: You also should think about moving the functions and the main loop into it's own (game) class, then you don't need the ugly "global" statement for accessing variables.

Comment: Thanks for the info im kinda new to python so i dont know much but the basics that is why i am trying to develop myself through simple projects appreciate the help

Comment: Each function has it's own scope. By default inside a function you can not write to a global (on module level defined) variable, it would create a new variable inside the function scope. With the global keyword, you import the variable into the functions scope and then can change it's value. If you are happy with one of the answers, you can mark the question as solved and accept the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, about half of your if else cases don't work. What is wrong with your code? The code is working and functioning. You can eliminate half of your elif cases because they will never execute. If and elif are sequential. If you still think your code is not working, debug slowly in a case by case basis. As in, set computer to a constant and test all cases.

I copy pasted your code and it worked fine at least for the apparent function. Removing the unecessary elif:

```
from random import randint
import sys
l2= ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = l2[randint(0,2)] 

wins = 0
losses = 0

player = False

while player == False:
    player = input("Rock,Paper,Scissors: ") #clean up the query
    print("Computer had ",computer) #You use this to debug to make sure the logic is working. 
    print("You entered ",player) # another print to make it look nicer
    if player == computer:
        print("Tie")    
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win Congrats")
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("You win Congrats")    
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Try again")
        else:
            print("You won")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid play Game Over for you")
    player = False
    computer = l2[randint(0,2)]
```

The logic is working just fine. Good luck to addding the rest of the features to your game.

I'd recommend trying using upper() to reduce failure from typos, and perhaps an exit string command as well. For the win/loss feature that you seem to want to add, just do a flag that adds to the win/loss number. You could also add other "commands" to your game with more if else cases. Good try and good luck.

Comment: Did it work for you? i applied the things that you said to my code but it wont still run properly i doesnt show any input from the user but i have a code for that it only shows the else statement on the terminal

Comment: can you post the output of your code? I am not sure which else is printing for you. And yes, it did work for me. Your initial code does not show any input from the user other than what is entered in the input() call.

Comment: Appreciate the tips im new to python so im trying to develop myself while i have break from school

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept any of the answers. All the best learning python. If you plan to use python for your future career, there's big interest in AI and you can try kaggle for some cool tutorials or play around with the OpenAI environment.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a rock paper scissors game

Here is some working code:

```
import random
computer = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
player = input("What do you choose?")
player = player.lower()
print(f"Computer picks {computer} and Player picks {player}")
if computer == player:
    print('Game is a tie, play again!')
if player == "paper":
  if computer == "rock":
    print('Player wins!')
  if computer == "scissors":
    print('Computer wins!')
if player == "rock":
  if computer == "paper":
    print('Computer wins!')
  if computer == "scissors":
    print('Player wins!')
if player == "scissors":
  if computer == "rock":
    print('Computer wins!')
  if computer == "paper":
    print('Player wins!')
```